# My function is only replacing two of the characters with their entity name?

Tags: javascript, html, function, replace, entity

I don't understand why the function is only replacing my '&', and my '"', with their respective entity names.

Could someone read it and see if they can help me out?

```
function convertHTML(str) {


  var HTML = ['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&apos;'];

  for(let i=0; i< str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == '&') {
      return str.replace('&', HTML[0]);
    }
    if(str[i] == "<") {
      return str.replace("<", HTML[1]);
    }
    if(str[i] == '>') {
      return str.replace('>', HTML[2]);
    }
    if (str[i] == '"') {
      return str.replace('"', HTML[3]);
    }
    if(str[i] == "'") {
      return str.replace("'", HTML[4]);
    }
  }
  return str;
}

convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana");
```

Comment: because you have `return` inside each `if` statement. remove them and keep the last one `return str;`

Comment: hmm i deleted all the returns except the last one and now none of them work? I'm still v. new to javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code works, you need to remove the `return` inside each if statement (notice that I cloned the string because you looping over it and `str.length` will keep changing after every replace)

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
  var HTML = ['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&apos;'];
  // clone input string
  let result = str.slice(0);

  for(let i=0; i< str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == '&') {
      result = result.replace('&', HTML[0]);
    }
    if(str[i] == "<") {
      result = result.replace("<", HTML[1]);
    }
    if(str[i] == '>') {
      result = result.replace('>', HTML[2]);
    }
    if (str[i] == '"') {
      result = result.replace('"', HTML[3]);
    }
    if(str[i] == "'") {
      result = result.replace("'", HTML[4]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

const result = convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana ' and < yes ");
console.log('result => ', result);
```

Another way is to define lookup and replace arrays and use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) to replace all occurrences

```js
function convertHTML(str) {
  const replace = ['&amp;', '&lt;', '&gt;', '&quot;', '&apos;'];
  const lookup = ['&', '<', '>', '"', '\''];
  lookup.forEach((item, index) => {
    const regEx = new RegExp(item);
    str = str.replace(regEx, replace[index]);
  });
  return str;
}

const result = convertHTML("Dolce & Gabbana ' and < yes ");
console.log('result => ', result);
```